# Swift/XCode declaring an array

Tags: swift, xcode

I tried to do

```
var title = [String]()
```

but an error popped up: Property 'title' with type '[String]' cannot override a property with type 'String?'

How to fix?

have also tried directly

var title = ["a", "b", "c"] and got same error

Comment: Obviously the code is in a class which already provides a `title` property like `UIViewController`. Use another name with plural form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable name `title` is reserved as `String` it's a property inside the base class `UIViewController` make it another name like

```
var titles = [String]()
```

Check [title](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621364-title)

Comment: Oh that makes sense - I changed the variable and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

its namespace error, you already have property with same name in yore class or yore parent class
for example:

**Wrong**:

```
class Example {
   let first: String
   let first: [String]
}
```

**correct**:

```
class Example {
   let first: String
   let second: [String]
}
```